# Display S.M.A.R.T. statistics for an SSD?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ssd, storage

I purchased a couple of used Intel 320-series 160 GB SSDs. I attached one of the drives to my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.8 using a SATA III to USB 3.1 cable.

When I attempted to view the drive statistics, it resulted in *S.M.A.R.T. Status: Not Supported*.

[image]

I'm fairly certain *S.M.A.R.T. Status: Not Supported* is wrong. According to [Intel Solid-State Drive 320 Series](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-specifications/ssd-320-specification.pdf), S.M.A.R.T. is supported. From the document (section 5.4):

> The Intel SSD 320 Series supports the SMART command set, which
>   consists of:
>
> - SMART READ DATA
> - SMART READ ATTRIBUTE THRESHOLDS
> - SMART ENABLE/DISABLE ATTRIBUTE AUTOSAVE
> - SMART SAVE ATTRIBUTE VALUES
> - SMART EXECUTE OFF-LINE IMMEDIATE
> - SMART READ LOG SECTOR
> - SMART WRITE LOG SECTOR
> - SMART ENABLE OPERATIONS
> - SMART DISABLE OPERATIONS
> - SMART RETURN STATUS
> - SMART ENABLE/DISABLE AUTOMATIC OFFLINE

How do I display the S.M.A.R.T. statistics for the SSD under OSX 10.8?

Answer (score 9):

Getting  the SMART status is possible with these disks but not if they are attached to USB. The necessary ATA commands usually aren't propagated through the USB-controller.

You can try to get that working though by using [OS X SAT SMART Driver](https://github.com/kasbert/OS-X-SAT-SMART-Driver).

Comment: Thanks klanomath. I prefer not to use a third party driver. Does Apple offer a command line tool to do it? Do you know if there are any Apple RARDARs covering Disk Utility and SMART drives? I'm interested in Apple-approved methods, and I'm having a heck of a time [searching for it](http://www.google.com/search?q=apple+radar+"s.m.a.r.t."+drive).